# MongoDB: merge two columns and convert type

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Within each document, there are two columns representing, respectively and as strings, whole and decimal numbers of price:

```
{
"prod_id": "1022"
"whole_price": "10",
"decimal_price": "50"
}
...
```

How could I perform a merge of those two columns, through an aggregation pipeline, and thus correctly represent the price as a float with a value of 10.5, for each pair of documents?

```
{
"prod_id": "1022"
"complete_price": 10.5
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$toDouble` and `$concat` in a `$project` stage to get the desired output:

This query output the field `complete_price` which is the values concatenated and a "." to create a double value. Then parsed to double to have as a number and not as a string.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "prod_id": 1,
      "complete_price": {
        "$toDouble": {
          "$concat": [
            "$whole_price",
            ".",
            "$decimal_price"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LJN5PD63p1S)

**Edit:**
Also, if your data can not be stable you can use `$convert` (instead of directly `$toDouble`) which has `onError` and `onNull` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ymA6JKqAwV6)